# Calculating network address

Tags: networking

I'm trying to calculate the network address but I'm not entirely sure if I've done it correctly. Let's say the IP is: 130.243.14.29 and the Sub-mask is: 255.255.254.0

After calculating I'm getting: 130.243.14.0, is this correct or is the last number wrong? Is the broadcasting address the same thing as network address?

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) in two parts for a complete tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

IP is: 130.243.14.29 and the Sub-mask is: 255.255.254.0

U have 510 IPs are useable

Network adress is 130.243.14.0

First ip address is 130.243.14.1

Last ip address is 130.243.15.254

broadcasting address is 130.243.15.255